# Efficiently merge all the contours present in a list in python

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, opencv, computational-geometry, shapely

I have a list of contours present in a list (around 12k). Many of the contours in this list overlap with each other. The task I need to perform is to efficiently merge all the contours which overlap with each other and get a new list with all the merged contours. The contours are merged based on a given condition such as intersection over union(IoU).

My current approach involves converting the list of contours into Geometry type in pygeos first, then finding the IoU and finally creating a dictionary containing which contours merge with which other contours. The code is as follows:

```
    
    detection_contours = np.asarray([Geometry(str(Polygon(np.squeeze(val)))) for val in contours_list])

    area_val = area(intersection(detection_contours[:, np.newaxis], detection_contours[np.newaxis, :]))
    union_val = area(union(detection_contours[:, np.newaxis]), area(detection_contours[np.newaxis, :]))

    iou = area_val / union_val

    for row_no in range(len(iou)):
        keep_to_merge_list[row_no] = np.where(ios[row_no, :] > match_threshold)[0].tolist()

    sorted_merge_list = {k: v for k, v in sorted(keep_to_merge_list.items(), key=lambda item: len(item[1]), reverse=True)}
    dest = {}
    seen = set()

    for k, v in sorted_merge_list.items():
        if k in seen: continue
        seen.add(k)
        new_v = [i for i in v if i not in seen]
        seen.update(new_v)

        dest[k] = new_v
```

The `dest` dictionary contains all the contours that merge with a given contour. For e.g.:

```
{1: [3, 4, 5],
2: [6, 7],
8: []
}
```

I then merge the contour present in the dictionary's key with the list present as it's value. If the value list is empty, it means the contour does not have any overlapping contour.

I want to surpass the dictionary creation step and directly merge the contour with it's overlapping contour.

Comment: Not sure whether more efficient or not, but if you know the "resolution" of your data you could draw the contours to an empty image and afterwards extract contours from that image.

Comment: @Micka the image size is 5000×7000. Can you further elaborate on how to draw and extract contours, since there are a lot of overlapping contours.

Comment: Create a black image. For each contour: cv.drawContours  each of them with color 255. Afterwards cv.findComtours. this however will fuse all contours that touch each other, so you cant choose an IoU.

Comment: @Micka I was also thinking about the same.

Comment: _why_ do you have 12k contours? where do they come from? there is value in "reviewing" your approach/design decisions.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz so I am running an inference (using an object detection model) and since the image of size 5000x7000, I am dividing it into small windows running inference on them, since these windows are overlapping hence so many contours. The actual number of contours is around 3000.

Comment: replace all that with a semantic segmentation model that supports fully convolutional operation (I don't know any that doesn't). then input size can be arbitrary, and output has the same dimensions as the input. you can then easily find the true connected components (contours).

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz can you please elaborate this. I didn't get what I should do after the semantic segmentation step.

Comment: the semantic segmentation gives you a "picture". simply run connected components or contour finding on that, instead of trying to piece together your detection windows.